# Passing $_POST values to output individual results information

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, superglobals

My goal is to create a general template to be used to `INSERT INTO testquiz` (a MySQL table). This will be used for storing quiz results and user information (name and email are the only user input in the database) from quiz takers. I am new to PHP/MySQL and feel like I am just stumbling around.

My problem is that I am unable to get the `$_POST` values that are generated by the quiz to appear in the database. I know the values are being generated because they will display with a basic echo. There is a 'send to email' feature that works with the values that is working as well. I can get this code to work if I manually assign values to the `$_POST` array by uncommenting the first comment block.

What am I missing here?

Sidenote: I'll take security suggestions as well. Thank you.

Code below (user specific information omitted):

```
<?php
//disable magic quotes (PHP book says it's a good idea)
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process))
    {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v)
        {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v))
            {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            }
            else
            {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = striplashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}


/* //Manually declare $_POST variables (can be disabled)
$_POST['v'] = '6.5.1';
$_POST['sp'] = 80;
$_POST['psp'] = 75;
$_POST['tp'] = 80;
$_POST['sn'] = 'user';
$_POST['se'] = 'abc123@fake.com';
$_POST['qt'] = 'Test Quiz';
*/
//Assign $_POST values to static variables???
$version = $_POST['v'];
$points = $_POST['sp'];
$passing_percent = $_POST['psp'];
$gained_score = $_POST['tp'];
$username = $_POST['sn'];
$email = $_POST['se'];
$quiz_title = $_POST['qt'];

//MySQL database connection PDO
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=quizresults', 'user', 'password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//Prepare input for database entry
try
{

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO testquiz (version, points, passing_percent, gained_score, username, email, quiz_title, date) VALUES (:version, :points, :passing_percent, :gained_score, :username, :email, :quiz_title, CURDATE())");
    $sql->execute(array(":version" => $version, ":points" => $points, ":passing_percent" => $passing_percent, ":gained_score" => $gained_score, ":username" => $username, ":email" => $email, ":quiz_title" => $quiz_title));

    //echo for debugging purposes
    echo $version . '<br />', $points . '<br />', $passing_percent . '<br />', $gained_score . '<br />', $username . '<br />', $email . '<br />', $quiz_title . '<br />', date(DATE_ATOM);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding quiz results to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//Calculate user score
$points_num = (int)$points; 
$passing_num = ((int)$passing_percent)/100 * (int)$gained_score;

//Write results to a text file
$f = fopen("result.txt", "w") or die("Error opening file 'result.txt' for writing");

fwrite($f, "--------------------------\n");
fwrite($f, "User name: ".$username."\n");
fwrite($f, "User email: ".$email."\n");
fwrite($f, "Quiz title: ".$quiz_title."\n");
fwrite($f, "Points awarded: ".$points."\n");
fwrite($f, "Total score: ".$gained_score."\n");
fwrite($f, "Passing score: ".$passing_num."\n");

if ($points_num >= $passing_num)
{
    fwrite($f, "User passes\n");
}
else
{
    fwrite($f, "User fails\n");
}

fwrite($f, "--------------------------\n"); 

if($f) 
{ 
    fclose($f); 
}

?>
```

Comment: If you can successfully enter data in DB when manually assigning, then this tells me that your form element's are not named. I.e.: `name="v"` etc. What errors are you getting back? Plus, show your form to be completely sure.

Comment: There is no form. It's a quiz generated by iSpring Quizmaker. Here is a link to their page regarding the data it outputs: [link](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/kb/articles/quizmaker/sending-quiz-results-to-server.html). I am not getting any errors.

Comment: POST variables rely on forms using `method="post"`, far as I know. Why do you think `$_POST['v'] = '6.5.1';` worked while `$version = $_POST['v'];` didn't?

Comment: There very well could be form functionality, but I really don't know. The .swf file that generates the $_POST data is generated by the iSpring plugin. I have tested it with just writing that info to a text file and it works. I am only having issues getting it to INSERT INTO testquiz (MySQL database).

Comment: You're trying to pull exterior data into your own server, I doubt that'll work. You'll most likely need to use CURL for that.

Comment: Well then, check your column names and table selection and make sure there's no typos, plus column types are correct. Other than that, your code looks fine to me. Try the answer given below.

Comment: No typos. The below answer also didn't work.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you then. If you say that hard coding the POST values work, then the plugin's at fault. PHP/SQL have done its job, far as I can see.

Comment: After a bit of investigation, I think Fred -ii- is correct. I will contact iSpring support. Thank you.

Comment: iSpring didn't help me much, but my PHP instructor did. I think the issue is that I am trying to use this code on a live server hosted by a third party. Therefore, I don't think I can use "localhost" as my host in the PDO for my connection to the database. I will try to work on that and see if it is the cause of my issue.

Comment: Come to find out, this code actually works. The issue was with the quiz configuration itself and not the code. This question is probably too localized, but for other iSpring users trying to make their own scripts to upload quiz results to a MySQL table, be sure that you set your script location to a valid value. Thanks for all that contributed to this question.

Comment: Glad to know you've found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix everything but

```
$sql->execute(array(":version" => $version, ":points" => $points, ":passing_percent" => $passing_percent, ":gained_score" => $gained_score, ":username" => $username, ":email" => $email, ":quiz_title" => $quiz_title));
```

should be:

```
$sql->execute(array("version" => $version, "points" => $points, "passing_percent" => $passing_percent, "gained_score" => $gained_score, "username" => $username, "email" => $email, "quiz_title" => $quiz_title));
```

(remove the `:` from the array. it is only for PDO to 'name' the variables).